# 2 virtual hosts, 1 server, 1 with dns and 1 without

Tags: virtualhost, apache-2.4

I have one Apache server from which I would like to host 2 sites, one has currently got DNS records propagated and the other currently does not.

in sites-enabled, I have the following

`sites-available/
├── 000-default.conf
├── default-ssl.conf
├── site1.hasDNS.co.uk.conf
└── site2.doesNotHaveDNS.co.uk.conf`

and in sites-enabled I have

`sites-enabled/
├── site1.hasDNS.co.uk.conf -> ../sites-available/site1.hasDNS.co.uk.conf
└── site2.doesNotHaveDNS.co.uk.conf -> ../sites-available/site2.doesNotHaveDNS.co.uk.conf`

and the contents of my /var/www is

`/var/www
├── holidaydirectuk.co.uk
├── html
└── site2.doesNotHaveDNS.co.uk`

And the contents of the .conf files are as follows:

site1.hasDNS.co.uk.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName site1.hasDNS.co.uk
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerAlias www.site1.hasDNS.co.uk
    DocumentRoot /var/www/site1.hasDNS.co.uk

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

site2.doesNotHaveDNS.co.uk.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName site2.doesNotHaveDNS.co.uk
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerAlias www.site2.doesNotHaveDNS.co.uk
    ServerAlias http://ip.address/ntcinvoice.co.uk
    DocumentRoot /var/www/site2.doesNotHaveDNS.co.uk

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

The problem is when I have both enabled, when I hit the url for site 1 (the one which has DNS), it resolves and serves up the site I'm expecting, however, when I try and hit the http://ip.address/site2.doesNotHaveDNS.co.uk its automatically redirecting me to the DNS host.

There is currently nothing in the html folder so not sure if that's my issue?

I also have a hostname set on the actual machine which matches site1.hasDNS.co.uk, could this maybe be the cause of the problem?

The host is a VPS hosted on [DigitalOcean](https://www.digitalocean.com/?refcode=a2984a839658)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you can try to use NameVirtualHost *:80

Comment: Thanks @c4f4t0r, whilst your comment gave me some ammo to start google'ing with I still couldn't it to do what I was after.

However, I now have DNS re-pointed at my VPS and all is working OK now, I was just trying to access the 2nd site solely by using the IP of the machine.